# Java sort one list based on another list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two different lists: one unsorted list with name and count properties and sorted list.

```
List<Pair<String, Long>> listA =  for example "A"->4, "B"->3, "C"->1
List<SortedItem> sortedList = [
        SortedItem(name=B, sortIndex=0),
        SortedItem(name=A, sortIndex=1),
        SortedItem(name=C, sortIndex=2),
        SortedItem(name=C, sortIndex=3),
        SortedItem(name=D, sortIndex=4)
    ]
```

and I would like based on "sortedList" sort the first unsorted list so result should be

```
List<Pair<String, Long>> res == "B"->3, "A"->4,"C"->1
```

I did with map, it's not really performant I guess there is much better solution for this ?

```java
List<Pair<String, Long>> sortedResult = sortedList.stream()
    .map(sortItem -> listA.stream().filter(item -> item.getFirst().equals(sortItem.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example so we can execute it easily, share the SortedItem definition, and the construction code for the list of pairs

Comment: You code is not "not really performant". It does not does the right thing at all, you are not sorting, but multiplying each entry regarding the amount of times each letter is un sortedList

Comment: Perhaps counter-intuitively sorting the sorted-list by sortIndex doesn't actually help. You will be accessing by `name` to find the `sortIndex`. You need either a `HashMap` or even a binary-tree/search. The performance hit here is looking up the to-be-sorted in the how-to-sort-them mapping. What I would call Collation Ordering.

Comment: Are there could be duplicates in both `sortedList` and `listA` or all `Pair`s are guaranteed to be unique? All indices from `listA` are expected to be present in the `sortedList` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First create a map, with sortedItem.name to its first index in the list

   ```
   AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();   
   // keep first index with (oldV, newV) -> oldV
   Map<String, Integer> map = values.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getName(), s -> index.getAndIncrement(), (oldV, newV) -> oldV));
   ```
2. Then use it to sort the list

   ```
   listA.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(pair -> map.get(pair.getFirst())));
   ```

---

```
List<SortedItem> sortedList = [
    SortedItem(name=B, sortIndex=0),
    SortedItem(name=A, sortIndex=1),
    SortedItem(name=C, sortIndex=2),
    SortedItem(name=C, sortIndex=3),
    SortedItem(name=D, sortIndex=4)
]
// becomes the map
{A=1, B=0, C=2, D=4}
```